# swagger: allow only one option from a enum definition for specific path

Tags: swagger, swagger-2.0

Let's say i have a definition such as:

```
definition:
  Operation:
    type: "string"
    enum: ["ADD", "REMOVE", "UPDATE"]
```

and want to document that the request for some path allways uses only the "ADD" operation as param. how can i achieve that? something like $ref: "#/definitions/Operation.ADD"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [swagger limit error codes of response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44307456/swagger-limit-error-codes-of-response)

Comment: It's not possible to limit an enum, you'll need a separate definition. See the ^^ linked question.

Comment: please check my answer below.

Comment: @Helen, thanks for your answer.